# Determine if the following function has a removable singularity at $z_0 = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = \frac{z}{z-1} $. The laurent expansion of $f$ around $1$ is

$$ f(z) = \frac{ z-1+1}{z-1} = 1 + \frac{1}{z-1}$$

and since in this case $b_1 = 1$, we know that $f$ cannot have a removable singularity at $z_0 = 1 $. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but it is probably faster to notice that $\lim_{z\to 1} f(z)$ doesn't even exist along the real axis, which it it would if the singularity were removable.

Comment: Okay, you are effectively observing that $f(z)$ has a pole at $z=1$, and this is not a removable singularity.

Comment: If $z_0 = 0$, then I can expand this using geometric series and we see that all the $b_k's$ are zero and so $f$ have a removable singularity at $z_0=0$ . correct?

Comment: It's a bit imaginative to say $f(z)$ has a "removable singularity" at $z_0 = 0$ since $f$ is defined there and continuous.  I would instead say $f$ is analytic at the origin (as your argument shows).  You could create a version of $f$ with a removable singularity at the origin by changing the definition, so that $f(0)$ is either undefined or defined to be some value other than zero (the natural limit).

Comment: Take $f(z)=g(z)$ with $g$ continuous and arrive to an absurd.